# How to proxy with nigthwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, proxy, nightwatch.js

I wanna use nightwatch.js for testing a complex javascript software.
I figured out how to simulate "user actions" like click etc.

My question is, how can i check and control the communication with the backends.

I mean i want to catch the outgoing http request, check whats in them, alter them if needed than check the response.

Is something like that possible? Is there any documentation or guide for nightwatch.js proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a proxy parameter in the 'desiredCapabilities' section of the nightwatch.json configuration file:

```
"firefox" : {
"desiredCapabilities": {
"browserName": "firefox",
"javascriptEnabled": true,
"acceptSslCerts": true,
"firefoxOptions" : {
  "args" : [
    "disable-extensions",
    "start-maximized"
  ]
},
"proxy": {
  "proxyType": "manual",
  "httpProxy": "your_proxy:8080"
}
```

}
},

Comment: Yes, thats clear but how can i write tests on that? 
I'm sending a lot of data with http requests to the backends. How can i read and alter them?